# Effective demotion?

Tags: united-kingdom, law

My company (in the UK) has recently been taken over by another and they are going to be merging the two organisations and the relevant teams. My current team is small and I work alone on my area of specialisation (with some input from the team manager, who basically reviews the results of my work and approves my suggestions for which projects I should work on next) and am responsible for that particular area. I have been informed by the managers that they want to change my job title from "Lead Analyst" (also includes my area of specialisation, but I have left that out) to "Analyst", citing that they do not have a lead title in their company.
They have tried to assure me it is not a demotion and not a reflection of my work, however they also want to change my reporting line so that I now report to essentially my equivalent in the team of the company that has acquired us (who I think has a similar level of experience to me), rather than to the head of the new, combined team. This would mean I will be lower down the hierarchy and also that I will effectively no longer be the one responsible for my area of specialisation, as that would fall to my new manager, who also does work on this area currently.
This feels very much like a demotion to me, both in name and practice.

From what I have read, such changes which I do not agree to could be a breach of contract and amount to constructive dismissal - but here's the catch: when I originally applied for the job (I've been here about 1.5 years), they first offered it with the title of "Analyst". I declined, stating that I did not think the title was appropriate given the level of experience they were requesting and they then came back and said they would make my title "Lead Analyst" instead, which I accepted. However, they requested  I sign the contract as is (with the title of Analyst), since they were keen to hire me and get it moving, and it would take too long to send the amended contract back through the legal team - I think because someone from that team was on holiday at the time (not sure if changing one phrase means the whole contract needs to be revised and re-approved, so maybe they were not being honest here?). I was did not want to lose the offer so I (naively) accepted and signed the contract with the title of Analyst with their promise (which was verbal I believe), that my actual title would be Lead Analyst.

So my questions are:

1. If my working title has been Lead Analyst, but it is only Analyst in my contract, can I still claim breach of contract? (or it is strictly based on what is in the contract?). Perhaps I would need to provide proof that that has indeed been my effective job title, in which case, what would suffice as proof?
2. If it's not breach of contract, does it still amount to a breach of trust and therefore could be seen as a constructive dismissal?
3. Does the fact I will no longer be "leading" my area of specialisation in practice, which was the main responsibility of the role I signed up/was hired for, still amount to a breach of contract, even without the job title change?

If the answers to any of the three questions above are yes, what would my next steps be? I feel quite dismayed by this whole situation, so any advice anybody could provide would be very welcome.

Comment: Point to ponder:  Are you really a lead if there is no-one to follow you?

Comment: Sadly we are not lawyers and will have a difficult time answering you. Generally though, you go by what is on the paperwork. Verbal is a case of proving your word against theirs and it gets very difficult. Next time, do not sign a contract unless you agree to everything on it

Comment: I'm going to have to VTC, as this is asking for advice on what jobs to keep/pursue.  Personally, you should always expect to be globally "bumped down" a notch when your company is acquired.  If you aren't happy, you should move on.  No job is worth being unhappy at.

Comment: Aside from the title and reporting changes, are you losing anything else? Benefit levels, pay, things like that?

Comment: Sadly this is where it is really a legal Q as complex  law like TUPE applies - Changing to reporting probably is not breach of contract unless it was a gross change senior developer to janitor for example.

Comment: @WesleyLong Probably not good advice for any EU country being "bumped down" would be a breach of TUPE laws